# PresentModalViewController with some frame

Tags: iphone, ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I want to present a modalViewController with a small frame and at the center of the view.

Is that possible?

Even if I set some frame to the viewController object, presentModelViewController is displaying that view in full screen mode.

Also, I have used modalPresentationStyle as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. I want to have frame even smaller than that.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** present a modal view controller that has a smaller frame size.

what you can try doing is to set the background of your modal view controller to transparent and then add the smaller sized view in the center (or where ever you wish to have it seen).

Answer (score 1):

Presenting a modal view will cover the entire view, if you don't wish to cover the entire view then you should create the view yourself, add it to the current view as a subView and then animate its transition yourself. It would not be a separate viewController because you're still operating within the bounds of the original view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Please follow below steps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(242, 60, 540, 312);
     self.controller.view.superview.frame = [self.view convertRect:rect toView:self.controller.view.superview.superview];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(242, 60, 540, 312);
     self.controller.view.superview.frame = [self.view convertRect:rect toView:self.controller.view.superview.superview];
}
```

You have to set frame of present controller after your controller setting (just before viewDidLoad method end).

Here I have considered iPad present view controller frame.

Comment: why would presenting a modal view post a UIKeyboardWillShowNotification ? fyi: modal view controller behaviors are different for iPhone and iPad

Comment: Agreed and thats why I have added my answer with iPad consideration. And I have added keyboard notification because most of the people are looking this controller with textfield means keyboard input setting.

Comment: @ABC1.. What exactly are you trying to do? Here I won't use any keyboard notification.. For some button action,  I need to prompt the user to enter his name with a small view. Could you explain it clearly what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: OK. If your present view controller doesn't contain any textfield then in this case no need to add any keyboard notification just only set frame in viewDidLoad method after present view setting. I have added this notification to handle modal view's frame. If view contains any textfield and user want to add text at this time keyboard up event fired and we have to change our present view's frame accordingly. In addition, please set rect properties according to your requirement. Here I have given only sample value.